# inject javascript code into safari on os x

Tags: macos, html, safari

I want to be able to speed up html5 video playback to 2x while using my browser as ipad agent.

Could I do this as a bookmarklet using the code found here?
http://www.learningapi.com/2012/04/variable-speed-playback-html5-video-feature/

Comment: If you figure it out, would love to see the result.

Comment: Sorry I never figured it out. :(